# При переборе в цикле каждое слово выводится с новой строки

Tags: python

При переборе в цикле каждое слово выводится с новой строки, как это исправить?

```
colors = ["red", "green", "white"]
for color in colors:
    print(color)
```

Чтоб выводилось все в одну строку

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте в `print()` окончание:

```
colors = ["red", "green", "white"]
for color in colors:
    print(color, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

у `print()` есть параметр 'end'. По умолчанию он равен `\n`. Но вы можете написать: `print(color,end = ',')`

Answer (score 2):

Можно вообще без цикла тогда:

```
print(*colors)
# red green white
```

Можно и разделитель указать:

```
print(*colors, sep=', ')
# red, green, white
```